# How to zip/unzip files Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, zip, unzip

I have some files on  `request.body.files` and I need to zip them and move to a directory. After that I need to unzip those files.

```
request.body.files
//zip
//Then a move the zip
//unzip
```

Comment: Yes, it is a Play app. I am using scala to to make uploads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985684/how-do-i-archive-multiple-files-into-a-zip-file-using-scala may help