# SBT how to publish an artifact generated from the run command

Tags: scala, sbt, publish

I'm attempting to compile and run scala code that generates a file in SBT (in this case its a swagger file).

the following sbt executes fine. The jar is built and executed and the swagger.zip file the execution creates is in the target directory. I can't, however, seem to get the zip file to get published to my artifactory repo like my standard jar files would.

Any idea on what I'm missing?

```
    publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := false 
    publishArtifact in run := true

    val myZipTask = taskKey[File]("swagger-zip")

    myZipTask := {
      file("swagger.zip")
    }

    addArtifact(Artifact("swagger", "zip", "zip"), myZipTask )
```

Comment: It seems that in the definition of the myZipTask you are not doing anything. It should zip the target, shouldn't it?

Comment: the code executed in the run command actually creates the zip file. All I want to configure is to have sbt publish the artifact that the execution created

Answer (score -2):

The `run` command doesn't trigger any publishing tasks, as that's not what it's for. I think you have tried to turn on publishing when `run` is called with "`publishArtifact in run := true`", but that code is not sufficient to achieve that; you'd need to attach many other `Tasks` to that command. That's not what you want anyway.

Your case fits entirely within the expected usage of the `addArtifact` helper (see [the docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Artifacts.html), and [the code](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/5ec8aac18bcc53fd6791d3a4caee2c3eefdd9440/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L2378))

As you need to run code to generate artefacts, you should provide that code as a `Task` argument to the `addArtifact` helper, i.e.

```
val myZipTask = taskKey[File]("return the swagger-zip file")
val runZipCodeTask = taskKey[Unit]("run the swagger-zip code")

// See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/faq.html, “How can I create a custom run task, in addition to run?”
// and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409993/defining-sbt-task-that-invokes-method-from-project-code
fullRunTask(runZipCodeTask, Compile, "ZipGeneratorMainClass")

myZipTask := {
  runZipCodeTask.value
  file("target/swagger/swagger.zip")
}

addArtifact(Artifact("swagger", "zip", "zip"), myZipTask)
```

Then run "`sbt publish`"

#### Working demo

See https://gist.github.com/RichardBradley/5384a5e0da2427df237f42fe512b30b8 for a working demo.

#### Note about scopes - consider generating this file in a meta-project, not the main project

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23416018/8261

Comment: the code that generates the zip file is what is being executed in the 'run' command. In this case the code that does this work is generating files and then zipping them into a single artifact. I can't just reference the code to execute this in the sbt because it needs to be built against current project code to do the work it needs to do.

Comment: @AndrewNorman, I understand, but it doesn't change my answer. You still need to write a Task which generates the zip and attach it with the "addArtifact" helper. If that Task needs to invoke classes built from your project, that's absolutely fine and SBT will sort out the dependency tree necessary. You shouldn't use the "run" command to do this, but create a new Task with the necessary dependencies (i.e. compiled classes, full classpath etc.). I'll see if I can make some time to write up a worked example in the next few days and update my answer with more detail, but I can't promise anything.

Comment: This is a broken window when it comes to SBT. It's so much easier and intuitive to write a Maven plugin to do these sort of needs

Comment: Not at all. I think this use case is actually easier in SBT than it would be in Maven. The problem for you is that you are familiar with how to do this in Maven but not in SBT. That is entirely your problem, and you won't get any benefit from blaming things on "broken windows" in SBT. SBT has plenty of problems, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: I disagree. Sbt's zip implementation is a very low level api. It's one that applies to a deep use case targeting individual file manipulation. While that is a powerful tool for the 1% scenarios, it doesn't address the common "99% of the time" scenario. Essentially this would be a simple  "create a zip file from everything in this directory" single call api. While it might be possible to string something together in a handwritten script involving multiple calls to the zip api, the point is that it shouldn't come down to that. A good 'simple build tool' should do this for you.

Comment: the added bummer here is that there is not a single example of how to do this common simple use case: "create a zipfile from a directory of files".  No example online, and no example on the plugin site. I do see examples of script that package wars from entire web projects and those examples require dozens of lines of non-intuitive DSL code. And its not the simple use case I describe above. I shouldn't have to write dozens of lines of script to do something I can do with one right click on a GUI OS

Comment: Q: "there is not a single example of how to do this common simple use case: "create a zipfile from a directory of files"". A.1) Yes there is, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985684 A.2) that's a different question to the one in the OP; you are moving the goalposts now in your efforts to blame SBT for all your woes

Comment: Rich, that link was for scala, not for sbt. I am currently writing native code in my assembly code to generate a zip file. That route doesn't artifact the file. If there was a post 'assembly' or post 'run' mechanism to zip the file in sbt that would archive, that would be great, but as noted such an example is non-existent and since sbt is its own DSL with little documentation beyond the mundane. It isn't very intuitive to know that such an option is actually offered by the script language

Comment: Actually, SBT build files are Scala code, so there's no need for separate examples; you can use that linked example to create a zip from a dir in SBT. We are getting off topic though. You asked how to publish an artifact generated by your own code in SBT, and I have provided working code that does just that. Personally, I think that this particular example is actually a good example where SBT shines in comparison to Maven, but I can see that I'm not going to dissuade you from blaming all your problems on SBT, so I'm going to stop trying now. Good luck with your project.